# How to send GPS coordinates from a android device /GPS Module to a server so i can fetch it from a app

Tags: android, server, gps

I'm new in android and servers, What i want is to send coordinates from a device Let's say Android Phone or GPS Module and store it in a web server so that  I can create a User Interface and map the coordinates.

The GPS coordinates will be updated like every 30 sec..

Comment: Please narrow your question, it is too broad (sounds rather like a "write this code for me" one). I'd suggest to ask about getting GPS coordinates first, but even before that check out if such questions were asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is for addressing issues not to give codes or something but i can give you a heading.

First of all you need a back-end API,you can for example create a web page in php that accepts POST request and put them in a database.

after that you can send the coordinates VIA an HTTP request to the web page you made from your android app.

you can create an other web page that reads the saved coordinates from the database and respond with them.you can then request that page from you other app.